# Google Visualization for drawing charts is not working in external Java Script File

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization, pie-chart

This is my html code. it contains one div & one external javascript file. if i use this external js file as a internal, it perfectly drawing the pie chart as per data but when i use it as an external js file its simply showing nothing.

code  .html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="externalscript.js"> </script>
</head> <body>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body></html>
```

externalscript.js

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    var dataArray =[['Task', 'Hours per Day']];
    var arr1=['Work','Eat','Commute','Watch TV','Sleep'];
    var arr2=[11,2,2,2,7]; (var n=0; n < arr2.length; n++) { 
    dataArray.push([arr1[n], parseInt(arr2[n])]);
    }
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: You're not including externalscript.js...

Comment: Now i edited. pls see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU NEED THIS.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawData);
```

```js
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 function drawData(){
    var dataArray =[['Task', 'Hours per Day']];
    var arr1=['Work','Eat','Commute','Watch TV','Sleep'];
    var arr2=[11,2,2,2,7]; 
    for(var n=0; n < arr2.length; n++) { 
    dataArray.push([arr1[n], parseInt(arr2[n])]);
    }
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawData);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head> <body>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body></html>
```